# Get a precise Json data Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I have trouble displaying in HTML a specific line that my fetch request returned.
This is my code :

```html
<script>

            fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=myapi&language=fr-FR&query=The%20Social%20&page=1&include_adult=false&year=2010")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data.results);
                    document.querySelector(".movies").innerText = data.results
                })
</script>
```

And this is what the request give me :

```json
[
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/65D7t8wgZFpjOTvIp1HQvHFY0fC.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            18
        ],
        "id": 37799,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Social Network",
        "overview": "Un soir d'hiver 2003, Mark Zuckerberg, étudiant à Harvard et expert en informatique, s'installe devant son ordinateur et se met à travailler avec frénésie sur une nouvelle idée, autour du développement de programme et de blogs. Ce qui prend forme dans cette chambre ce soir-là deviendra très vite un réseau communautaire à échelle mondiale et une révolution dans la communication. Seulement six années et quelques 500 millions d'amis plus tard, Mark Zuckerberg est devenu le plus jeune milliardaire de l'histoire... Cependant, pour cet entrepreneur, la réussite amène à la fois des complications personnelles et légales.",
        "popularity": 30.558,
        "poster_path": "/cvUfwhoAReL4e5eegFCHM73rIda.jpg",
        "release_date": "2010-10-01",
        "title": "The Social Network",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.3,
        "vote_count": 10059
    }
]
```

And I want to return the "overview" line into HTML.

Any Idea ?

Comment: `data.results[0].overview`, I should think. Are you unsure how to interpret the structure of the data, or something? `data` contains an array called `results`, whose first index contains an object featuring the property you're interested in. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the array `results` and look for `overview` like this: `data.results[0].overview`

```js
fetch("https://run.mocky.io/v3/b61f89fc-33ab-4863-ab71-c4e3b2682fd3")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // console.log(data.results);
    document.querySelector(".movies").innerText = data.results[0].overview
  })
```

```html
<div class="movies"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, I Know m'y question is Bad for people who Know JavaScript but I just starterd this language